# How many matrices $C \in \mathrm{M}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $\det(C-A)=\det(C-B) = 1$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields

I am studying the special unit-graph $G$ on $M_3(\mathbb{F}_q).$ Now, I want to estimates the upper bound for the second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matric of $G.$ One of questions that I need is the following question:

For $A, B \in M_3(\mathbb{F}_q).$ How many matrices $C \in M_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that both of  $C - A$ and $C-B$ are in $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q),$ i.e, $\det(C-A)=\det(C-B) =1$?

Comment: Let $D:=A-B$. The question is equivalent to asking for how many pairs of matrices $M_1, M_2\in \mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$, $M_1-M_2=D$.

Comment: Or how many $M \in SL_3(\mathbb F_q)$ have $M-D\in SL_3(\mathbb F_q)$.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is given and the number $s$ of matrices $M$ s.t. 
$\det(M)=\det(M-D)=1$ is required. Of course, $s$ depends on $D$. We randomly choose $D$ for $q=2,3$. Using Grobner basis theory, we obtain that follows:

$q=2$; $s=56$ (in 60% of the tests), $s=48$ (in 30% of the tests), $s=72$ (in 10% of the tests).

$q=3$; $s=1566$ (in 50% of the tests), $s=1647$ (in 50% of the tests).

For $q=5$, it's a long way.